# Can't import Chem from rdkit in Anaconda Python 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04, rdkit

I install the Anaconda 4.5.4 with Python 3.6.5 and install rdkit (with command "`conda install -c rdkit rdkit`") and I'm trying to import the Chem and does not works.

```
from rdkit import Chem

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/wandre/anaconda3/envs/flaskapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rdkit/Chem/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>

    from rdkit.Chem.rdmolops import *

ImportError: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this? Where is my error?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't need to add SOLVED keyword to the title. Look at the other questions: just mark the correct answer as solved

Comment: What type of OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Just run `sudo apt-get install libxrender1` and it works